# Best way to store JSON Web Token into Cookie?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, cookies

I have a POST request called login that gets back a JSON response, in that JSON response is token:"23iu728427224 .... " along with username:"...."

I am looking at cookie-parser but the documentation is horrible, any advice here?

How do I store the token as a HTTP cookie? 
How do I retrieve a specific value from a cookie? (Fore future request that require a Token)

Right now in my post request for login (I'm using request-promise)

it goes

request(options)
.then(function (response) {
res.cookie('auth', response);

In my console I type document.cookie and I get this as my response, "auth=j%3A%7B%22success%22%3Atrue%2C%22username%22%3A%22mark%22%2C%22message%22%3A%22Here%20is%20your%20token%22%2C%22token%22%3A%22eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.lubhT8AAcnwy2lC4idcYeCsm2O7bTod-ob9i1FNUGTk%22%7D"

Does this mean I did it correctly? If so on another note, how do I then get that token value? I see that the cookie doesnt store spaces so does this automatically get parsed?

Answer (score 2):

You would want something like this to save just the token:

```
res.cookie('auth', response.token);
```

That should save the JWT itself to the auth cookie, rather than the full response object.

Comment: Ahh good advice now the cookie is, just "auth=sdfdsffssdfs". Do you know how I can then access this auth cookie in another js file? I am stuck here.

Comment: You will want to access the cookie using vanilla JavaScript. Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

There are third-party libraries as well, which make it easier, but you certainly don't need them (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

Comment: Eh I don't want to worry about having to decode the cookie for semi colans and such, is there some sort of middleware where I can get justCookie('auth') ?

Comment: If you don't want to manually do it, take a look at the library I linked. It will be as easy as: Cookies.get('auth'); to get the JWT.

You can use Passport-js for authentication middleware if you want. Take a look here: http://blog.slatepeak.com/refactoring-a-basic-authenticated-api-with-node-express-and-mongo/

Comment: Ah thank you for your help. I am using jscookie npm package, however it's not working is it because I am storing my cookie wrong? When I do document.cookie I get auth="dfsd......" however when I try to do jscookie.get('auth') my page breaks down :l

Comment: I think thats what the problem is, I think I am not storing the cookie correctly. I used another cookie package and when I try to get 'auth' it returned undefined

Comment: This code is working for me as is on another app:
return res.cookie('token', userToken, { maxAge: 604800000 }).status(200).redirect('/dashboard');

You are definitely importing cookie-parser (const cookieParser        = require('cookie-parser');) and telling your app to use it (app.use(cookieParser());) right?

Comment: I'm using the express generator which has var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); app.use(cookieParser());

Comment: shouldnt the fact that when I do document.cookie and the cookie shows auth=sdfdsfsd mean I'm storing the cookie correctly?

Comment: Well is it because I'm setting the cookie in another route? On my login page is where I create the res.cookie. I'm trying to access the cookie on my create listing page

Comment: Because after I get the token and store it in the cookie, I do an immediate redirect res.redirect(/postlisting)